# Create columns in table dynamically using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a way to create columns in a table dynamically using Laravel 5.2. Please assist if it does ?

Comment: Well, that's not a recommended thing to create dynamic columns in db.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan I also had the same feeling but could you please explain why its not recommended ?

Comment: Structural level changes in database from application is not good to manage database, optimize database.